# Javascript show alert two times before redirect

Tags: javascript, alert

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--

alert('You will be redirected');


window.location = "http://www.google.com/"

//-->
</script>
```

How to change the code so that the alert is shown twice before redirecting to google?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--

alert('You will be redirected');
alert('You will be redirected');


window.location = "http://www.google.com/"

//-->
</script>
```

Why you'd want to do this I don't know, but that will do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<--
for(vari=0;i<2;i++)
  {
    alert('You will be redirected');
  }

window.location = "http://www.google.com/"

 //-->
</script>
```